# D3 Selection is not updating existing classed text elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, css-selectors

I am using d3 v6 to create a group, `bucket`, holding subgroups that contain different SVG-elements. After creation, I would like to update the data for the svg text elements in each group of class `textbox`, but I am unable to select and update the elements. In the code below, I tried updating only text elements of class `large`, but nothing happens. Am I not using the class selectors correctly?

This is how I create the groups:

```
const bucket = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'bucket')

const textboxes = bucket.selectAll('g')
        .data(data)
        .join('g')
            .attr('class', 'textbox')
            .attr('transform', d => `translate(0, ${d.index * spacing})`)

const rects = textboxes.append('rect')
         .attr("width", 5)
         .attr("height", 50);

const textlarge = textboxes.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'large')
        .text(d => d.text);

const textsmall = textboxes.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'small')
        .text(d => d.text2);
```

Above code is resulting in the following DOM structure:

```
<svg>
    <g class="bucket" transform="translate(50, 0)">
        <g class="textbox">
            <rect></rect>
            <text class="large">A</text>
            <text class="small">2</text>
        </g>
        <g class="textbox">
            <rect></rect>
            <text class="large">B</text>
            <text class="small">1</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This is how I am currently trying to update the data in the boxes (in this excerpt I am trying to only update text of class `large`):

```
let bucket = container.select('g.bucket')
    .selectAll('g.textbox')
    .data(newdata)
    .join('g')
    .attr('class', 'textbox')
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(0, ${d.index * spacing})`)

const textlarge = bucket.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'large')
    .text(d => d.text));
```

Comment: I recommend you read up on what `.append` does and how selectors work. To select all text with class large, use `text.large` or `.large`. You're appending new elements, not selecting existing ones.

Comment: You mean something like `container.select('g.bucket').selectAll('g.textbox').selectAll('text.large')` ? And add the data after that?

Comment: If you're talking about updating the texts, then yes. Though you can just use `container.selectAll('text.large')` directly if you want, no need for the intermediate steps

Comment: Ok, yes, `container.selectAll('text.large')` works. I also realized that I need to remove `join()` because I want to replace the content entirely. That's why it kept creating new elements